# Value of global variable resetting for some reason i dont understand

Tags: c, arrays

Ok- ive managed to create a function that inputs a two dimensional array of 5 items that you can choose from, prints the items and then asks you for which you would like, and then takes that item you chose and places it into a reciept which is another 2d array that i defined globally in main. here is an MCVE:

```
char receipt[20][200];
static int arrnum=0;

void choose(char arr[5][200]){
  int i;

  for(i=0;i<=4;i++){
    printf("%s\n",arr[i]);
  }

  printf("Enter in your choice");
  int choice;
  scanf("%d",&choice);
  strcpy(receipt[arrnum],arr[choice-1]);  
  printf("receipt[0]:%s\n",receipt[0]);
  arrnum++;

}
    void printreceipt(){
    int qnum=0;

    printf("Receipt:\n");
    int itmnum=0;
    while(qnum<arrnum){
        printf("Item %d:\n%s",itmnum,receipt[qnum]);
        itmnum++;
        qnum++;
    }

}
int main(){
    char strings[5][200]=    {"string1","string2","string3","string4","string5"};
    choose(strings);
    printreceipt();
    return 0;

}
```

In my bigger program its in a loop so that i can go through the process multiple times and have different choices that i picked inside the receipt. Inside of main i can call receipt[x] and it works properly.I used a static global variable arrnum to keep track of how many items are inside the receipt and where to place the next one.Arrnum increments everytime choose() is called. But inside the function i created to print a receipt for some reason arrnum resets to 0.

Comment: In this code you never change `arrnum` so it starts off as `0` and remains on `0` forever. The loop in `printreceipt` never enters the loop body because `0 < 0` is false

Comment: your global variable resets because you are trying to reset it yourself.  Try to access it and changing its value throug other assignment statements in the code and see how it handles the required task. Also please write things in the main function, which will automatically restrict the global vs local access functionality of the program....

Comment: See this -`strcpy(receipt[arrnum],arr[choice-1]);` `choice` is entered by user , but what if `choice` is `0`  ???  Then in `strcpy` it would be `arr[-1]` . So , that will also create a problem . And you don't validate the input .

Comment: @CodeMan I still don't see what you are trying to say ... there is no code here to "reset" arrnum

Comment: I think i might have fixed it by adding a parameter to printreceipt(const int arnum) and calling it in main like printreceipt(arrnum)

Comment: @M.M arrnum increments each time choose() is called and in my project its looped several times.

Comment: @confusedbeginnerp You still don't seem to be grasping the concept that you must post a *complete program* that *shows the problem*.  So far you have posted a nearly-complete program that *does not* show the problem, and various incomplete program fragments, and descriptions of code.  You are just wasting everybody's time until you post a complete program that shows the problem.  Compile and run the exact code you are planning to post, before you post it, and check that it shows the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed your program up a bit. This version works without the need to make a variable static. It basically passes the index number from the mainline to the choose function then to the print receipt function.

I also added some basic error checking to make sure the number is within range.

You will need to play with the code to make it work for your needs.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char receipt[20][200];

int choose(char arr[5][200],int arrnum){
  int i;
  for(i=0;i<=4;i++){
    printf("%s\n",arr[i]);
  }
  int choice=0;
  while (choice < 1 || choice > 4){
    printf("Enter in your choice ");
    scanf("%d",&choice);
  }
  strcpy(receipt[arrnum],arr[choice-1]);
  printf("receipt[%d]:%s\n",arrnum,receipt[arrnum]);
  arrnum++;
  return arrnum;
}
void printreceipt(int arrnum){
  printf("Receipt:\n");
  int itmnum=0;
  while(itmnum<arrnum){
    printf("Item %d: %s\n",itmnum+1,receipt[itmnum]);
    itmnum++;
  }

}
int main(){
  int items=0;
  char strings[5][200]=    {"string1","string2","string3","string4","string5"};
  items=choose(strings,items);
  // items=choose(strings,items); <--add more of these lines if you want more items on the receipt.
  printreceipt(items);
  return 0;

}
```